# Reboot after shutdown (Ubuntu 14.04 (also 12.04); Dell latitude E7440)

Tags: shutdown, 14.04, reboot

I have a rather serious shutdown/reboot issue with my Ubuntu OS on my brand new Dell latitude E7440 netbook. The issue does not seem to depend on the OS version: it occurs with 12.04, 13.10 and now with 14.04. I've waited for the new LTS in the hope that it would solve my problem, but that is not the case.

After shutting down my ubuntu, my laptop reboots about two seconds after shutdown. I've tried many things to solve it, but none of them did the job. I have the 64 bit version of 14.04 installed and boot in legacy boot mode with secure boot disabled. The behavior is independent from a power cable/usb device/ethernet cable being plugged in. Strange enough, however, it does sometimes stay powered off after being used for several hours...

I know there have been several treats concerning shutdown/reboot issues, but none of them provides an answer to my specific case. I ran diagnostics in the BIOS to recover any potential hardware problems, but there were none. If you have an answer or even a clue on how to solve this issue, it will be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could some attached equipment be sending a wake signal?

Comment: Hi fleamour. The reboot also takes place without any cable/device/monitor connected, so that is not possible.

Comment: In my case only happens when no power cable is connected.

Comment: I just discovered that only when the bluetooth receiver (USB adapter) is connected (laptop running on battery) this problem happens.

Comment: There seems to be a bug reported about this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1346269

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I experienced exactly the same problem on my new computer Intel i5-4440 processor and Intel DB85FL motherboard (4th Gen). First I faced this problem with Ubuntu 13.10. and subsequently after upgrading to 14.04 LTS.

I did the following recently to solve this problem of SHUTDOWN and automatic REBOOT again withing a second or two.

I have Intel Visual BIOS. On power up I pressed F2 > POWER > Wake On LAN from S4/S5.

This has 3 options. 1. Stay Off, 2. Power on - Normal Boot, and 3. Power on - PXE Boot. My computer was set to #2, which was making it automatically REBOOT after SHUTDOWN. I now changed to #1 option mentioned above. Now it is okay.

Hope this would work for you as well. Best wishes.

Comment: bluepearlsky, thanks a lot! I would have never been able to fix this myself. Your fix did the job! I still consider it very weird that this is needed though...  In my case (Dell latitude E7440, SSD, core i7) you need to go to 'power management' in the BIOS and there are 5 options for 'wake on LAN'. Like the answer above, you need to pick `disable' from those five.

Comment: @Kees, if this answer solves your issue please take a minute and check the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Comment: You are welcome, Kees. I am glad you could fix the problem. Have a nice time and take care.

Comment: I have "wake on LAN" off so it doesn't solved it for me.

Comment: I basically went into my BIOS and turned off every option with the word "wake" in it... I don't need my computer raising itself from the dead like some zombie. This was an HP zBook 15, just in case any other people are suffering with it... it turned on in my bag and overheated itself through a 90 minute drive... seems to be fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same case on my Acer Aspire E1-470G using Ubuntu 14.04. These steps worked for me.

1. Type in terminal

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```

   then find a line

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   Modify it to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" acpi=force apm=power_off
   ```
2. Type in terminal `sudo nano /etc/grub/modules` then add `apm power_off=1` under line lp. Save and close the terminal.
3. Update the GRUB

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

Comment: No luck for me. In my system, there is no /etc/grub/ directory, and the "modules" file is in /etc/modules.

Comment: I skipped step 2, but the problem was still resolved, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my new intel motherboard and core i5 processor, Ubuntu 14.04.1 64bit OS. I tried to disable wakeup from LAN from bios and did not get any success.

Then I modified

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" acpi=force apm=power_off
```

Still no success.

One of my colleagues suggested that, though mine was a desktop PC, I should install `laptop-mode-tools`, and surprisingly it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem with 14.04 on a Gigabyte GA-MA78GM-S2H based desktop. Tried all the BIOS settings I've seen suggested around the web with no luck.

Thought it might be a USB related wake. Used non USB mouse and keyboard and problem solved.

May not be a solution to laptop owners but thought i'd share the info on a few boards.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the wake on via LAN option is working well with my case.

Machine: HP Elitebook 850 G2
O/S: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Disabling "Wake on LAN" in the BIOS solves the reboot problem for my **HP EliteBook 840 G2**.
(Ubuntu 15.04, Kernel: 3.19.0-21)