# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes during shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. Today suddenly I am seeing that it freezes during shutdown. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: I have determined that on my 16.04 system this is caused by the service `cups-browsed` failing to shut down.  I am in the process of figuring out how to fix this now.  If I issue a `sudo service cups-browsed stop` before shutdown, it never hangs.

Comment: [Chaitanya Baranwal](https://askubuntu.com/users/749116/chaitanya-baranwal) had [mentioned in an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/966239) that was since deleted for unclear reasons (though perhaps it was intended as a comment) that the method given in [Ernesto Barechesto's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/792086) to [Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown/restart](https://askubuntu.com/q/764568) fixed this problem. As far as I know there isn't really any way to distinguish these questions, and an answer for one is likely to apply to the other, so I think we should make this a duplicate as @Zanna says.

Answer (score 2):

The launchpad discussion (linked below) has several suggestions you may find work for you.  Assuming your cause is the same, it is suspected that swap and/or systemd are the issue.  Try these possible fixes:

```
sudo systemctl reboot
```

(works occasionally for me, but not 100% of the time)

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

or even a combination of the two

```
sudo swapoff -a && sudo systemctl reboot
```

Though, when I tested this, the swapoff part took > 10 mins anyway.  For shutdown, replace 'reboot' with 'poweroff.'

As a side note, I have had this same issue on my PC from Ubuntu 15.04 through the current 16.04.  It is possibly connected to how long the computer has been in use.  If it's been on a while, it will take a really long time to shut down or reboot (10 mins or more on a black screen or screen with a cursor).

I have found this issue reported a few places that you may find helpful:

[15.04 laptop won't shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630341/after-switching-to-ubuntu-15-04-laptop-wont-shutdown)

[Extended discussion on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1464917)

Comment: Thanks for replying... I must add that my system hangs during shutdown but it's very occasional.. I mean to to say some days it hangs but some days it does not hang at all.. Smooth shutdown after long hours of use as well as short time use... I tried to check system log also but I didn't understand what was the problem....

Comment: Did you try the above?  I guess you would have to try it for a while since your issue is sporadic.  I'm not the best at analyzing the logs so I'm not much help there.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with ASUSE402SA-WX030T.

I solved installing [mainline kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds) 4.5.6

**Update:**
While I solved freeze during shutdown installing 4.6 version, I experienced random ones during normal use.
So I installed 4.5.6 mainline version and now everything is fine.

Steps to solve (please note that url provided can goes dark also):

```
mkdir kernel-4.5.6
cd kernel-4.5.6

#choose correct version for your arch
for f in linux-headers-4.5.6-040506-generic_4.5.6-040506.201606011632_amd64.deb linux-headers-4.5.6-040506_4.5.6-040506.201606011632_all.deb linux-image-4.5.6-040506-generic_4.5.6-040506.201606011632_amd64.deb
do
    wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.5.6-yakkety/$f
done

sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Reboot and you are done

Answer (score 0):

I tried several methods including: editing `/etc/default/grub`, run `sudo swapoff -a` before shutdown, etc... But one of those worked for me.

Turning off `USB 3.0 legacy mode` in the BIOS worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and tried `sudo swapoff -a` and `systemctl poweroff`, which did not solve the problem. Finally, this command did fix it:

```
sudo service cups-browsed stop
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm a newbie.  I have an old Inspiron E1405 with unresolved internal wireless issues and no installed Bluetooth.  I have an external USB wireless device instead. I tried a bunch of posted answers which didn't work re restart and shutdown.

However... someone talked about **BIOS settings** so I looked there. I made a few changes and now it seems to work. Changes I made in the BIOS were:

- I placed startup in *auto*, not *simple*.
- I turned Bluetooth off in settings.
- I shut off the wireless in the BIOS too, because I was using an external wireless USB dongle instead.

I think that was all I did, but now it seems to work. Who knew? It still is booting up well and shutting off and restarting well.