# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs on shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

I know that there are other questions similar, but I will give more details about the problem.

When I try to shutdown/restart the system hangs forever.
This appens on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit. It appens on the same machine on an upgraded Kubuntu (14.04 » 16.04),
on a fresh installed Lubuntu 16.04 and event on a live CD (iso booted from hard-disk with grml-rescue).

It appens if I shutdown/restart from the Desktop Enviroment and if I do it from the terminal.

The issue is not appening on an Ubuntu 14.04 installed on the same hard-disk.

## fdisk

I've tried to run a fdisk on the partition but no errors were found.

## irqpoll

I've tried to add the `irqpoll` parameter to the system boot

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic root=UUID=c50c612d-813b-4e76-a6d0-92e697658b7a ro irqpoll $vt_handoff
```

## bios usb3

Someone has resolved by turning off usb3 legacy support on the bios, but my motherboard is very old, I have no usb3 support on the bios

## systemctl and swap

This answer https://askubuntu.com/a/769953/23130
talked about 2 possible problems: **systemctl** and **swap**

```
sudo swapoff
sudo systemctl reboot
```

but none of theme work

## shutdown debug

the previous answer pointed to an interesting Launchpad discussion
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1464917

where there is an introductive text that says:

> If you are experiencing a shutdown hang, please file a separate bug report and follow the debugging instructions described in the 
>   "Debugging boot/shutdown problems" section of /usr/share/doc/systemd/README.Debian.gz to check if there are any hanging jobs at shutdown. 
>   Capturing a screen photo of "journalctl -b" in the rescue shell might be enlightening.

So the debbuging instructions says to

```
sudo systemctl enable debug-shell
sudo halt
```

then when the shutdown hangs you have a console on VT9 <kbd>CTRL+ALT+F9</kbd> where you can do

```
systemctl
```

to find units with state *active*

```
systemctl list-jobs
```

all jobs listed are with state *waiting*, the only one with state *running* is `upower.service` which is bold.

So I powered off the PC and started again, now in a terminal I've done

```
sudo systemctl list-jobs
```

The output is

```
JOB UNIT           TYPE  STATE  
1341 upower.service start running
1 jobs listed.
```

so I tried to turn it off and disable it for the future

```
sudo systemctl stop upower.service
sudo systemctl disable upower.service
sudo systemctl mask upower.service
```

I then tried again to shotdown, with the debug console

```
sudo systemctl enable debug-shell
sudo halt
```

but the shutdown freezes as usual, plus now I cannot even access the debug-shell.

Booting without the *quiet splash* grub options I can see that the shutdown hangs on the output line

```
Reached target Shutdown
```

These are the *syslog* lines about the shutdown

```
Aug  5 11:45:12 pc-dev udisksd[2930]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 at /media/luca/TOSHIBA EXT on behalf of uid 1000
Aug  5 11:45:12 pc-dev ntfs-3g[3141]: Version 2015.3.14AR.1 integrated FUSE 28
Aug  5 11:45:12 pc-dev ntfs-3g[3141]: Mounted /dev/sdc1 (Read-Write, label "TOSHIBA EXT", NTFS 3.1)
Aug  5 11:45:12 pc-dev ntfs-3g[3141]: Cmdline options: rw,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,uhelper=udisks2
Aug  5 11:45:12 pc-dev ntfs-3g[3141]: Mount options: rw,nodev,nosuid,uhelper=udisks2,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sdc1,blkdev,blksize=4096
Aug  5 11:45:12 pc-dev ntfs-3g[3141]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Aug  5 11:45:16 pc-dev com.canonical.indicator.application[2749]: (process:3129): indicator-application-service-WARNING **: Application already exists, re-requesting properties.
Aug  5 11:45:19 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Daemon for generating UUIDs.
Aug  5 11:45:28 pc-dev spideroak_inotify[3253]: Program started
Aug  5 11:45:36 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Aug  5 11:45:36 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopped Read required files in advance.
Aug  5 11:45:36 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
Aug  5 11:45:40 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Early root shell on /dev/tty9 FOR DEBUGGING ONLY.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopped Daily apt activities.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopped Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopped Stop ureadahead data collection 45s after completed startup.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev org.freedesktop.Notifications[2749]: xfce4-notifyd: Fatal IO error 11 (Risorsa temporaneamente non disponibile) on X server :0.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopping Light Display Manager...
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev ntfs-3g[3141]: Unmounting /dev/sdc1 (TOSHIBA EXT)
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopping Disk Manager...
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev ModemManager[2245]: <info>  Caught signal, shutting down...
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopping Daemon for power management...
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopped target System Time Synchronized.
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev dbus[2266]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1' unit='polkitd.service'
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Aug  5 11:45:53 pc-dev rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="2228" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="2232" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev loadkeys[764]: Caricamento di /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Set console keymap.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting LSB: AppArmor initialization...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting Set console font and keymap...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting Create Volatile Files and Directories...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd-tmpfiles[958]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev systemd[1]: Starting Show Plymouth Boot Screen...
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev apparmor[943]:  * Starting AppArmor profiles
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Aug  5 11:48:26 pc-dev kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
```

This is my [lshw output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxeigwu09m69s4b/lshw.txt?dl=0)

Can someone help me? To me is unbelievable that such a severe bug affects a LTS.

Comment: What is your hardware configuration? Are you maybe with and Nvidia card on an Asus Laptop?

Comment: It's not an Asus Laptop but yes I have a Nvidia card, can you please tell me a command to get the output to give you a complete answer?

Comment: Which drivers do you use? Try to [start with `nomodeset`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do). You can add `sudo lshw -sanitize` to the question for giving us the full hardware involved.

Comment: I've tried to boot with `nomodeset` but unfortunately it doesn't help. I've attached my `lshw` on the question

Comment: Do you have an SSD for your swap partition?

Comment: No, unfortunately no SSD here!

Comment: I have Asus laptop and SSD for swap partition, what is the procedure there?

Comment: I believe that the problem is related to the kernel 4.x. I have another partition with Ubuntu 14.04, the problem started even here after moving from kernel 3.x to 4.x

Comment: having the issue on 19.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution.
I was searching for a solution for another problem: `lsusb` command was hanging forever, so I found this post
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2301619

I then remembered that I had a USB3 PCI Card plugged on the mother board but not powered, after removing it the problem is solved.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here on brand new Asus L502S. I tried Mint, Mate, Ubuntu - all the same. Problem is common. I tried everything which can be found regarding this problem over the forums.

Eventually I gave up when I found this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1594023

Check if you issue is the same and I hope U don't waste another day on this, as I did.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't undestand, what in the bug report convinced you to give up?

Comment: Because it is confirmed bug in the OS - I believe it is not solvable by simple tricks as modifying flags of 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT'. I tried every suggested solution which can be found over the internet and non of those solved problem in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, Hope you too.

I have Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

*STEPS I DID FOR SOLVE*

- Press CTRL + ALT and T
- In terminal paste sudo xedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
- Write your user password
- In the bottom of the windows add:

`blacklist dw_dmac
 blacklist dw_dmac_core`

- Save and Quit
- **I did Follow step, but don't know if is neccesary:** In the same terminal add: `sudo update-grub`
- Reboot once (maybe could keep with issue, force reboot) Thats It. I
  Did it and the PC now colud PowerOff/Reboot/Suspend and everything.

NOTICE: **For this to work you will need to eraser quite splash in the Grub Steps** for this:

- Press CTRL + ALT and T (open the terminal)
- Paste this sudo xedit /etc/default/grub
- Write your user password
- In the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` eraser `quiet
  splash`
- Save and Quit
- In terminal paste sudo update-grub

Notes: This work for ASER E-11 with previous Windows8.1 and now with Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

*Cons: In the Start or ShutDown the computer will show only console, but It'll works.*

Comment: unfortunately is not working for me

Comment: Do you have Lubuntu?

Comment: What is most interesting to others is: how did you get the idea of blacklisting dw_dmac? Which debugging procedure led you to that kernel module?

Answer (score 0):

I know that OP said that `nomodeset` didn't help, but since this is the top Google result for this problem, I thought I'd put in what finally helped me.

I tried everything to do with grub in all the answers and tried all other proposed answers I could find.

In the end, when I booted with `nomodeset`, it shutdown fine, which was my first clue.

I had just updated to the newest nvidia driver (381), and prime was set to 'intel' mode. Changed it back to nvidia, one more hard shutdown (settings don't change fully until boot) and it works fine with prime set to nvidia.

Hopefully this may help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Add the following line:

```
blacklist i82975x_edac
```

source : https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148033

Comment: Doesn't work for me