# GNOME 16.04 Reboot after Shutdown

Tags: gnome, 16.04, shutdown, reboot

My PC always reboots 5 seconds after its turned off. I looked at [Reboot after shutdown (Ubuntu 14.04 (also 12.04); Dell latitude E7440)](/q/452750), but:

- the top rated answer didn't help since I have no power options in the F2 menu. I changed wake on lan to disable, didn’t help.
- The 2nd answer had 3 steps. I did step 1 and 3. Didn’t help. When I enter the command for step 2 the terminal is empty.

If it helps, I have an acer v5-571.

`cat /proc/acpi/wakeup`:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
P0P1      S4    *disabled
GLAN      S4    *disabled
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
PXSX      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0
        *disabled  platform:rtsx_pci_ms.0
RP04      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
RP05      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
PEG0      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG1      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
PEG3      S4    *disabled
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
```

So, in the other thread you posted to me, he had `XHC EHC1 EHC2` as the sources of the reboot, so I tried to take the shortcut and disable them as well, but again (maybe because I lack a word like with the last command), my access is denied.

I entered his solution:

```sh
for device in XHC EHC1 EHC2; do
    if grep -Fe "$device" /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep -qFe enabled; then
        echo "Disabling wakeup on $device"
        echo "$device" > /proc/acpi/wakeup
    fi
done
```

Unfortunately the format isn’t kept, so it is a bit of a mess, hope you still see through.

Comment: Does it also wake up immediately after you suspend it?

Comment: @PeterNerlich no, it waits like 5 seconds, always the same interval.

Comment: Yes, but not only on shutdown but also on standby?

Comment: @PeterNerlich on standy it doesnt...

Comment: Ok, else I would have suggested to take a look at [this post "Ubuntu wakes up after few seconds of sleep"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep)

Comment: i took a look, thanks.

I tried to follow as n00b but first step
doesnt work:

if i enter /proc/acpi/wakeup
as suggested here, the access is denied.
how can i get access?

Comment: you want to display the contents of the file, so use `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` or open it with an editor, e.g. `nano /proc/acpi/wakeup`

Comment: @PeterNerlich ok, with your command i can see the list..! i posted an edit above since it had too many characters...! problem now is disabling the particuliar setttings. do you agree i should try his solution as well? diasbling XHC EHC1 EHC2 as a test?

Comment: Yes, and you need admin rights to change this. Type `sudo` before your command to grant it higher rights, you will be promted for your password once. So either run your script with `sudo` or change `*enabled` to `*disabled` in there by hand with `sudo nano /proc/acpi/wakeup`

Comment: @PeterNerlich i disabled everything but the SLPB (since i presumed that this is like the powerbutton from my brotherpost) but it never worked. So i toggled them and checked if theyre disabled, and i tried to turn the pc off, but in any case it restarted. what else can i do? should i post something like the syslog? how do i do that?

Comment: I am afraid that in that case I don't know how to help you.

Comment: @PeterNerlich lets try it with this post maybe? http://askubuntu.com/questions/452750/reboot-after-shutdown-ubuntu-14-04-also-12-04-dell-latitude-e7440#comment595065_452759