# Ubuntu 16.04 reboot after shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, reboot

I have a laptop (HP Probook 450 G0) with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 in a dual boot configuration. Recently I upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 using do-release-upgrade. After the upgrade, when I shutdown Ubuntu, the laptop automatically turns on after a few seconds (pretty similar to the problem in this thread [Ubuntu 16 reboots seconds after shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760851/ubuntu-16-reboots-seconds-after-shutdown)). Windows 10 still works fine. I read a lot of boards looking for answers and tried some solutions, which are:

- Turning off Wake up on LAN and Wake up on USB in BIOS settings.
- Running `apt update` and `apt upgrade`.
- Unplugging all USB devices before shutdown.
- Editing `grub` file with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" acpi=force apm=power_off`.
- Trying other ways to shutdown like `sudo shutdown -h now`, `sudo poweroff -f`, etc...
- Reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04 (Erase and install from Live USB).

None of the above solutions work for me. The only solution that worked is to turn off WiFi using the shortcut button, and only then the computer will not start itself after shutdown. 
Some side-notes:

- Sometimes after login I can't use any USB port (I tried with my mouse and USB flash stick).
- Even when I connect to the internet using an Ethernet cable, it still notifies/prompts me to connect to available WiFi connections.

Can someone help me with this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure Windows has released all the resources on its end... Get rid of Windows `fast boot` or `quick start` or other similar Windows gimmick and see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this dude.

```
Type in terminal

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

then find a line
```

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

```
Modify it to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" acpi=force apm=power_off

Type in terminal sudo nano /etc/grub/modules then add apm power_off=1 under line lp. Save and close the terminal.

Update the GRUB

sudo update-grub
```

Source: [Reboot after shutdown (Ubuntu 14.04 (also 12.04); Dell latitude E7440)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452750/reboot-after-shutdown-ubuntu-14-04-also-12-04-dell-latitude-e7440)

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

## Switch Case ( Solve Dual OS error )

### Try 1:

download any other version of ubuntu (not what you have downloaded or updated). e.g. install Ubuntu22.04 https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

then set dual boot with windows.

### try 2

The bug maybe in windows 10.
update windows 10 to windows 11, its free.

or https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11

### try 3

maybe both the OS have some Boot level problem.
so The most accurate solution is: Install from scratch

- Clear your whole computer, delete both OS (save nessessary data before it)
- install windows 11 : https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11
- install Ubuntu22.04 https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop (dual boot)

## Default Option: (If none worked):- Change Laptop.