# Ubuntu 18.10 Restarts seconds after shutdown

Tags: 18.10

I'm using HP Probook 650, Running ubuntu 18.10 , I noticed that when i have a usb flashdrive or AC power connected the Laptop turns off without a problem.

Without a USB flash or a power plug, the laptop does not turn off.

Any ideas as to how to resolve this? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that _if_ you have no USB drive connected _or_ you are on battery power that a shutdown gesture eventually results in a reboot? Make it clear with an [edit] exactly what you are doing and what happens. Be as specific as you can.

Comment: Hw are you turning it off? Check your power settings. There are different options for "on battery" and "on AC" and for powerbutton and lid closing actions. Might be something there.

Comment: To power it off I must have my flashdrive plugged in or power cable. Without that I have to hold the power button force shutdown. But using ubuntu shutdown button the laptop restarts just after 2 seconds

Comment: You should provide us with more information about the error.

Please, after restarting, execute the command:

journalctl -b

Then edit your post and paste the result.

Comment: This will show you all of the journal entries that have been collected since the most recent reboot.

Comment: You may want to check the ["Wake on LAN" setting](https://askubuntu.com/a/452759/8005) in your BIOS menu.

Comment: Did you check on kernel boot logs? `journalctl -b -k -p4 | grep -i "acpi\|power"`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue  by disabling USB 3.0 in bios settings.